# How to override Login/authenticate method in the Grails spring-security-core plugin?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am attempting to use the Grails Spring Security Core plugin. I would like to override the login functionality, which is 'login/authenticate'. I searched through the spring-security-core plugin source and wasn't able to find the 'authenticate' method, and its not in the generated LoginController.

https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugin/springsecurity/LoginController.groovy

Any guidance would be most appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you want to achieve by overriding the login functionality? Please specify it,  so people might be able to help you.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I would like to override the login functionality

Comment: Yes, you want to override the login functionality. But what is your end goal ? I mean you want to provide multiple username(user can login using email + mobile number as username etc..) functionality to user ? OR SSO ? OR something else ?

Comment: I would like to add a login log

Answer (score 0):

Spring security is built around filter chains. The correct way would be to create a new filter. You probably need to download the spring grails security core plugin and look at classes like GrailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter to get a feel for how to do it. Your way forward might be to copy GrailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, install it as your authentication filter, and put logging in there.